# Method invocation failed op_addition

Tags: powershell, psobject

in this script i am pulling info from my SQL servers. i create the psobject and then i attempt to += each object into the $results table so that i can get a complete final report.
for some reason if i run the script all the way through it gives me the error

> Method invocation failed because [system.management.managementobject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'

But if i run the script line by line I do not get the error.

```
$Results = @()
$servers = get-content .\computers.txt
ForEach ($server in $servers) {
   # Ping the machine to see if it's on the network
   $results = Get-WMIObject -query "select StatusCode from 
Win32_PingStatus where Address = '$server'" 
   $responds = $false   
   ForEach ($result in $results) {
      # If the machine responds break out of the result loop and indicate success
      if ($result.statuscode -eq 0) {
         $responds = $true
         break
      }
   }
         If ($responds) {
      # Gather info from the server because it responds
      Write-Output "$server responds"
   } else {
      # Let the user know we couldn't connect to the server
      Write-Output "$server does not respond"
   }



# Check to see if a directory exists for this machine, if not create one
   if (!(Test-Path -path .\$server)) {
      New-Item .\$server\ -type directory
   }




#get-WMI-Information

   function getwmiinfo ($srv) {
   # Get ComputerSystem info and write it to a CSV file
   gwmi -query "select * from
       Win32_ComputerSystem" -computername $srv | select Name,
       Model, Manufacturer, Description, DNSHostName,
       Domain, DomainRole, PartOfDomain, NumberOfProcessors,
       SystemType, TotalPhysicalMemory, UserName, 
       Workgroup | export-csv -path .\$srv\BOX_ComputerSystem.csv -noType
   # Get OperatingSystem info and write it to a CSV file
   gwmi -query "select * from
       Win32_OperatingSystem" -computername $srv | select Name,
       Version, FreePhysicalMemory, OSLanguage, OSProductSuite,
       OSType, ServicePackMajorVersion, ServicePackMinorVersion |
       export-csv -path .\$server\BOX_OperatingSystem.csv -noType
   # Get PhysicalMemory info and write it to a CSV file
   gwmi -query "select * from
       Win32_PhysicalMemory" -computername $srv | select Name,
       Capacity, DeviceLocator, Tag | 
       export-csv -path .\$srv\BOX_PhysicalMemory.csv -noType
   # Get LogicalDisk info and write it to a CSV file
   gwmi -query "select * from Win32_LogicalDisk
       where DriveType=3" -computername $srv | select Name, FreeSpace,
       Size | export-csv -path .\$srv\BOX_LogicalDisk.csv -noType
}
   # Get the server info
   getwmiinfo $server



#Get-SQLInfo
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO") | Out-Null



# Create an ADO.Net connection to the instance
$cn = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
"Data Source=$server;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=master");
# Create an SMO connection to the instance
$s = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $server

# Set the CSV output file name and pipe the instances Information collection to it
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "GEN_Information.csv"
$s.Information | export-csv -path $outnm -noType


# Set ShowAdvancedOptions ON for the query
$s.Configuration.ShowAdvancedOptions.ConfigValue = 1
$s.Configuration.Alter()



# Create a DataSet for our configuration information
$ds = new-object "System.Data.DataSet" "dsConfigData"
# Build our query to get configuration, session and lock info, and execute it
$q = "exec sp_configure;
"
$q = $q + "exec sp_who;
"
$q = $q + "exec sp_lock;
"
$da = new-object "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter" ($q, $cn)
$da.Fill($ds)


# Build datatables for the config data, load them from the query results, and write them to CSV files
$dtConfig = new-object "System.Data.DataTable" "dtConfigData"
$dtWho = new-object "System.Data.DataTable" "dtWhoData"
$dtLock = new-object "System.Data.DataTable" "dtLockData"
$dtConfig = $ds.Tables[0]
$dtWho = $ds.Tables[1]
$dtLock = $ds.Tables[2]
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "GEN_Configure.csv"
$dtConfig | select name, minimum, maximum, config_value, run_value | export-csv -path $outnm -noType
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "GEN_Who.csv"
$dtWho | select spid, ecid, status, loginame, hostname, blk, dbname, cmd, request_id | export-csv -path $outnm -noType
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "GEN_Lock.csv"
$dtLock | select spid, dbid, ObjId, IndId, Type,Resource, Mode, Status | export-csv -path $outnm -noType


# Set ShowAdvancedOptions OFF now that we're done with Config
$s.Configuration.ShowAdvancedOptions.ConfigValue = 0
$s.Configuration.Alter()

# Write the login name and default database for Logins to a CSV file
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "GEN_Logins.csv"
$s.Logins | select Name, DefaultDatabase | export-csv -path $outnm -noType


# Write information about the databases to a CSV file
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "GEN_Databases.csv"
$dbs = $s.Databases
$dbs | select Name, Collation, CompatibilityLevel, AutoShrink,
   RecoveryModel, Size, SpaceAvailable | export-csv -path $outnm -noType



   foreach ($db in $dbs) {
   # Write the information about the physical files used by the database to CSV files for each database
   $dbname = $db.Name
   if ($db.IsSystemObject) {
      $dbtype = "_SDB"
   } else {
      $dbtype = "_UDB"
   }

# Write the user information to a CSV file
   $users = $db.Users
   $outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + $dbname + "_Users.csv"
   $users | select $dbname, Name, Login, LoginType, UserType, CreateDate | 
       export-csv -path $outnm -noType

$fgs = $db.FileGroups
   foreach ($fg in $fgs) {
      $files = $fg.Files
      $outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + $dbname + "_DataFiles.csv"
      $files | select $db.Name, Name, FileName, Size,
 UsedSpace | export-csv -path $outnm -noType
      }
   $logs = $db.LogFiles
   $outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + $dbname + "_LogFiles.csv"
   $logs | select $db.Name, Name, FileName, Size, UsedSpace |
 export-csv -path $outnm -noType
   }


   # Create CSV files for each ErrorLog file
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "_ERL_ErrorLog_.csv"
$s.ReadErrorLog() | export-csv -path $outnm -noType
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "_ERL_ErrorLog_1.csv"
$s.ReadErrorLog(1) | export-csv -path $outnm -noType
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "_ERL_ErrorLog_2.csv"
$s.ReadErrorLog(2) | export-csv -path $outnm -noType
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "_ERL_ErrorLog_3.csv"
$s.ReadErrorLog(3) | export-csv -path $outnm -noType
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "_ERL_ErrorLog_4.csv"
$s.ReadErrorLog(4) | export-csv -path $outnm -noType
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "_ERL_ErrorLog_5.csv"
$s.ReadErrorLog(5) | export-csv -path $outnm -noType
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "_ERL_ErrorLog_6.csv"
$s.ReadErrorLog(6) | export-csv -path $outnm -noType



$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "Gen_Information.csv"
$Gen_Information = Import-Csv $outnm
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "Gen_Databases.csv"
$Gen_Databases = Import-Csv $outnm
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "Box_ComputerSystem.csv"
$Box_ComputerSystem = Import-Csv $outnm
$outnm = ".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "Box_OperatingSystem.csv"
$Box_OperatingSystem = Import-Csv $outnm


$Gen_Info = $Gen_Information[0]
$Gen_DBs = ForEach($object in $Gen_Databases){$object.Name}
$Box_OS = $Box_OperatingSystem[0]
$Box_CS = $Box_ComputerSystem[0]
$Box_OSOS = $box_os.Name.Split("|")

#region Correct SQL Version Name
#correct Version Name
if($Gen_Info.VersionString -like "8.*.*.*")
    {
    $Gen_InfoVers = "SQL Server 2000"
    }
    elseif($Gen_Info.VersionString -like "12.*.*.*")
    {
    $Gen_InfoVers = "SQL Server 2014"
    }
    elseif($Gen_Info.VersionString -like "10.*.*.*" -and $Gen_info.VersionString -notlike "10.5*.*.*")
    {
    $Gen_InfoVers = "SQL Server 2008"
    }
    elseif($Gen_Info.VersionString -like "9.*.*.*")
    {
    $Gen_InfoVers = "SQL Server 2005"
    }    
    elseif($Gen_Info.VersionString -like "10.5*.*.*")
    {
    $Gen_InfoVers = "SQL Server 2008r2"
    }
    elseif($Gen_Info.VersionString -like "11.*.*.*")
    {
    $Gen_InfoVers = "SQL Server 2012"
    }
    elseif($Gen_Info.VersionString -like "13.*.*.*")
    {
    $Gen_InfoVers = "SQL Server 2016"
    }
    else{$Gen_InfoVers = "Unknown Version"}
#endregion


$object = New-Object psobject -Property @{
Server = $Box_CS.Name
OS = $box_osos[0]
Edition = $Gen_Info.EngineEdition
SQLVersion = $Gen_InfoVers.ToString()
TotalDBs = $Gen_DBs.count
DatabaseName1 = $Gen_DBs[0]
DatabaseName2 = $Gen_DBs[1]
DatabaseName3 = $Gen_DBs[2]
DatabaseName4 = $Gen_DBs[3]
DatabaseName5 = $Gen_DBs[4]
DatabaseName6 = $Gen_DBs[5]
DatabaseName7 = $Gen_DBs[6]
DatabaseName8 = $Gen_DBs[7]
DatabaseName9 = $Gen_DBs[8]
DatabaseName10 = $Gen_DBs[9]
DatabaseName11 = $Gen_DBs[10]
DatabaseName12 = $Gen_DBs[11]
DatabaseName13 = $Gen_DBs[12]
DatabaseName14 = $Gen_DBs[13]
DatabaseName15 = $Gen_DBs[14]
DatabaseName16 = $Gen_DBs[15]
DatabaseName17 = $Gen_DBs[16]
DatabaseName18 = $Gen_DBs[17]
DatabaseName19 = $Gen_DBs[18]
DatabaseName20 = $Gen_DBs[19]
DatabaseName21 = $Gen_DBs[20]
DatabaseName22 = $Gen_DBs[21]
DatabaseName23 = $Gen_DBs[22]
DatabaseName24 = $Gen_DBs[23]
DatabaseName25 = $Gen_DBs[24]
DatabaseName26 = $Gen_DBs[25]
}

$object = $object | select Server,OS,SQLVersion,Edition,TotalDBs,DatabaseName1,DatabaseName2,DatabaseName3,DatabaseName4,DatabaseName5,DatabaseName6,DatabaseName7,DatabaseName8,DatabaseName9,DatabaseName10,DatabaseName11,DatabaseName12,DatabaseName13,DatabaseName14,DatabaseName15,
DatabaseName16,DatabaseName17,DatabaseName18,DatabaseName19,DatabaseName20,DatabaseName21,DatabaseName22,DatabaseName23,DatabaseName24,DatabaseName25,DatabaseName26
$object | Export-Csv ".\$server\FinalReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force

$Results += $object

}

$Results | Export-Csv ".\Final\FinalReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Comment: Please point out exactly where this error is being thrown and distill your code down to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of posting your entire script.

Comment: I don't like format string like in your example. Try: `".\$server\${instnm}GEN_Configure.csv"` instead of `".\" + $server + "\" + $instnm + "GEN_Configure.csv"`. Try to reformat all. And `$Results += $object` should be `$Results += @($object)`.

Answer (score 12):

@alroc has a valid point, that's a lot of code. You can try typing `$Result` as an `[array]`.

change

```
$Results += $object
```

to

```
[array]$Results += $object
```

Comment: This just worked for me on my own class that I created. I needed an array of those objects.  I was getting a `op_addition` error before I prepended `[array]` on to my `+=` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your error happens here

> ```
> $Results += $object
> ```

You are using the same variable name for holding different data. The first time you are gathering the results from a WMI query.

> ```
> $results = Get-WMIObject -query "select StatusCode from Win32_PingStatus where Address = '$server'"
> ```

Then you add it again when you get the error. Arrays do support addition but `$results` is not an array when the error is generated.

You have some other issues but mainly change the variable name to address this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the variable **outside the forEach**

> $Results = @()